# How to initialize Userform Listbox where there sometimes is a default selected value

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am using a VBA userform in an Excel template with a list box with multiple selections allowed from the list.

In some cases when we open the "userform" some values are already selected by default.

I have tried to deselect all values in initialize() sub but still the values are selected by default.

Initialize() code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
          ListBox1.Selected(i) = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: show your code in Initialize sub

Comment: @DisplayName I have updated the code

Comment: You could use the Userform_Activate Event, Put your code there and see if it works.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda Already tried, but still the same issue. I think it is a bug bcoz if I open the same template in some PC it would work perfectly. If anyone faced a similar issue with listbox it would be a great help

Comment: @IshanJuneja can you show how this would look like? Is it always the first element which si selected or alwys the same few? Have all laptops the same version of excel?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda I wont be able to show the data. The selection is random and also on random useforms. The template has 3 userforms. One lappi is showing randomly first two entries selected for 1st useform while the other lappi as 1st and 4th entry selected for 3rd userform

Comment: @IshanJuneja My suggestion is to find the source of the random selection and not to patch it with the suggested code. Go through your code and try to find all instances where you alter some selection in the userform. Then debug accordingly. I'm sorry that I cannot give a better advice, if you can find the source of the selection then the solution might be already obviouse.